# ASP.NET Core React-with-Redux template dispatch issue

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, react-redux

I am working on this project where we're using this template from MS and it's all working nice but for this particular task I am in a need for 'default' dispatch method from redux so I can focus on some form inputs and I cannot figure out how to get it.

```
import { ApplicationState } from '../../../store/index';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as GlobalState from '../../../store/Global';
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import SelectHour from '../Selects/SelectHour';
import Select from '../Selects/Select';
import MultiSelectComponent from '../Selects/MultiSelectComponent';
import Days from '../Days';
import { getFormInitialValues } from 'redux-form';
import { Field, focus, blur } from 'redux-form';
import SelectHour from './SelectHour';

class WorkingDays extends React.Component<Props, State> {
...
}

export default connect(
     (state: ApplicationState) => state.global,
     GlobalState.actionCreators
)(WorkingDays) as typeof WorkingDays;
```

How can I get access to dispatch so I can use it something like this?

```
this.props.dispatch.focus(something, something)
```

Answer (score 0):

`dispatch` is a function, so you can't make `this.props.dispatch.focus(something, something)` work.
But can get `this.props.focus(something, something)` by this way:

```
export default connect(
     (state: ApplicationState) => state.global,
     (dispath) => ({
         focus: (value1, value2) => {
             const action = yourAction(value1, value2)
             dispath(action)
         }
     })
)(WorkingDays) as typeof WorkingDays;
```

I have never worked with MS react-redux template so I do not know what your `GlobalState` is look like!